# Equivalent to select html tag in C# components?

Tags: c#, .net, combobox

I'm using the combobox component, it seem equivalent to the select html tag,but not have the value in combobox? 
For example:

**HTML select:**

```
<select name="foo">
<option value="baa">xxx</option>
<option value="foo">yyy</option>
</select>
```

if the value selected is `xxx` the value returned is `baa` for me

it is possible do this with some component of C#?

I hope this is clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are several controls available which are similar , you can use regular combobox , which exactly behaves this way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the regular ComboBox control, but with a little tweak. Each item added in the ComboBox is an `object` and when rendering, it calls the `ToString()` method.

We can create a custom class to add as ComboBox item:

```
public class ComboBoxItem
{
    public ComboBoxItem(string value, string text)
    {
        Value = value;
        Text = text;
    }

    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}
```

Now, you can create instance of the above class and add to the `ComboxBox.Items` collection.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem("1", "Green"));
    comboBox1.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem("2", "Blue"));
    comboBox1.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem("3", "Yellow"));
}
```

And you can access the selected item which is the instance of the `CombBoxItem` by casting `comboBox1.SelectedItem` to `CombBoxItem`

```
var comboBoxItem = (ComboBoxItem) comboBox1.SelectedItem;
comboBoxItem.Text  //Green/Blue/Yellow
comboBoxItem.Value //1/2/3
```